# TextTransform.exe from the Command Line - Can't Find .dll

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, t4, poco

I am using the reverse poco generator `.tt` file. This works perfectly in VS. No issues, but I want to run it from the command line in order to add it to my Azure pipeline.

**Here is my final call:**

```
set ttFilePath=C:\Project\Root\Path
set idePath=C:\VS Path ToTo\Common7\IDE
set entityToolsPath=C:\VS Path To\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes

"%idePath%TextTransform.exe" -out "%ttFilePath%MyTtFile.cs" -I "%entityToolsPath%" -a !!NamespaceHint!MyNamespace -a !!ProjPath!.\ProjectFolder\ProjFile.csproj -a !!T4Path!.\ProjectFolder\MyTtFile.tt -dp T4VSHost!Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.Directives.FallbackT4VSHostProcessor!"%idePath%Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll" "%ttFilePath%MyTtFileName.tt"
```

**This fails with the following error.**

```
'C:\Project\Root\Path\%VSAPPIDDIR%EntityFramework.dll'
```

For some weird reason it's looking for the EntityFramework.dll in my project folder. This would be easily remedied (adding it in the folder) if it wasn't including this weird variable that isn't set.

```
%VSAPPIDDIR%
```

I figure I could set this var in my environment variables, but there should be a better workaround.